# How do I install ubuntu on my macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple

I want to wipe my computer and only have ubuntu as os, just like I have done in the past but want to make sure it all goes well as I have never had a mac before! please guide me as to what I can do to make this mac fully functional under linux!